# Schedule Access import to SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, automation, ssms

**SSMA for Access to Console (AccessToSQL)**

I created a project with `SSMA for Access` and successfully imported an `Access file` to the `SQLServer`now, I want to automatize the task with `SSMA for Access Command Prompt` Also I found the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313057(v=sql.110).aspx) to be quite information lacking.

*Edit:*

With the provided sample XML and some [minor tweaks](https://gist.github.com/EndermanAPM/c4c338b2fd7b3121e51fff09b6e733c4) I'm able to migrate the tables, I think my problem is solved.

I think it's because it's trying to migrate the access tabes and `queries` there is any way to **only** migrate the `tables`?
(I should add that migrating only the tables with the `SSMA(GUI)` works just fine.)

**SSMS import Data**

I also tried to import the data using the Server Management Studio, but since it's an express edition I'm unable to save the package as described in [this process.](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s231/schedule_data_import_in_sql_server_pt2.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Affter fiddling arround for two days I finally managed to make `SSMA for Access Command Prompt` work by editing the sample script to fit my needs, you can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/EndermanAPM/c4c338b2fd7b3121e51fff09b6e733c4).

Now I'll schedule the task with the Windows built-in scheduler and that should do the trick.